# submenu is hidden behind google map

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, google-maps

On [home page](http://stefanrepac.com/PD/index.php) (pocetna) when you go over "dizajn" vertical menu working fine, but the problem appears when you go in ["kontakt"](http://stefanrepac.com/PD/kontakt.php) page, menu is just behind google map, and i dont know how to fix it. If someone know solutio i will be grateful. Thank you

code for javascript is like this ( this code was copied from video how to create vertical menu, because i dont know that much staff about coding. Thank you for understanding )

```
$("document").ready(function() {

    // Function triggered when mouse hovers over a menu item
    // Looking for a LI item that has a UL for a child element
    // If it does trigger the function on mouseover
    $('#sidebarmenu li a').parent().has('ul').mouseover(function() {

        // offset() returns the top & left relative position on the doc for LI
        tagOffset = $(this).offset();

        /* I use the following to get the tag name for this 
        getTagName = $(this).get(0).tagName;
        alert(getTagName); */

        // Get distance from the left for the LI
        offsetLeft = tagOffset.left;

        // Get distance from the top for the LI
        offsetTop = tagOffset.top;

        // Move the new popup 180px to the left (Width of parent UL) 
        popOutOffsetLeft = offsetLeft + 226;

        // Get the id for the first UL contained in the LI
        closeParent = $(this).closest("ul").attr("id");

        // Checking if the UL is a second level of third level popup menu
        if (closeParent == 'sidebarmenu')
        {
            // Make menu visible and move it into position on the document
            $(this).find('ul').first().css({'visibility' : 'visible', 'left' : popOutOffsetLeft + 'px', 'top' : offsetTop + 'px'});
        } else {
            // Find offset for the UL that surrounds the third level popup
            secondOffset = $(this).find('ul').last().parent().offset();

            // Subtract the top offset from the second menu to position properly
            secondOffsetTop = secondOffset.top - offsetTop;

            // Correct the positioning on offset left
            secondOffsetLeft = offsetLeft - 10;

            // Make menu visible and move it into position on the document
            $(this).find('ul').last().css({'visibility' : 'visible', 'left' : secondOffsetLeft + 'px', 'top' : secondOffsetTop + 'px'});
        }
    });

    // When the mouse moves off the menu hide everything
    $('#sidebarmenu li a').parent().has('ul').mouseout(function() {
        $(this).find('ul').css({'visibility' : 'hidden'});
    });

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the console, you have not included jquery in kontakt page.

Insert this in your kontakt.php

```
<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: OMG you are right! I dont know how i didnt saw that. Thank you very very much.

Answer (score 0):

**Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined**  Got this message while inspecting

jQuery File is missing in `kontakt.php`

Answer (score -1):

Assign "z-index" css properties both for map and for menu containers, and the menu's one must be greater than map's one, e.g. 100 for menu and 99 for map.